# Python, customTkinter not assigning Label to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to check wether an entry is left empty, the user entered the correct id in it or if the user entered an incorrect id.
The idea I have is to basically destroy the label for each entry status and creating a new one so that the text don't overlap.
When I wanted to implement that, it appears that the variable always remains empty even if the condition that creates the label is executed first.

Here is my function:

```
def updateWrongIdText(id):
    wrongIdText = None
    if doesIdExist(id):
        if wrongIdText is None:
            print("Still no widget in variable")
    else:
        if len(id) == 0:
            wrongIdText = customtk.CTkLabel(master=loginFrame, text="Sorry, Studnet Id case cannot be empty", font=('Chalkboard', 12), text_color="red")
            wrongIdText.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.8, anchor = "center")
        else:          
            wrongIdText = customtk.CTkLabel(master=loginFrame, text="Sorry, this Student ID is not registerd in our Library", font=('Chalkboard', 12), text_color="red")
            wrongIdText.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.8, anchor = "center")
```

And this is how the id is retrieved; after the click of a button and then sent to both `doesIdExist()` and `updateWrongIdText()`.

```
def onLoginButtonClick():
    id = idEntry.get()
    password = passEntry.get()
    doesIdExist(id)
    updateWrongIdText(id)
```

I'm also new to StachOverflow so idk how to produce a minimal reproducible example.

Below as an MRE:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as customtk

label = None

app = customtk.CTk()
app.geometry("800x600")
app.title("Library Application")



def Button1Click():
    if button1.winfo_exists() == 1:
        label.destroy()

def Button2Click():
    global label
    label = customtk.CTkLabel(app, text="This is a test.")
    label.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.5, anchor="center")

button1 = customtk.CTkButton(master = app, text="Click me to delete", command=Button1Click)
button1.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.6, anchor="center")

button2 = customtk.CTkButton(master = app, text="Click me to create", command=Button2Click)
button2.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.4, anchor="center")


app.mainloop()
```

And Thank You in advance :)

I've tried every answer I found on Google, nothing worked.

Comment: This code never seems to assign `id`. Please provide a complete [mcve] so we can see how you're defining `id`.

Comment: I edited the post accordingly, thank you Bryan.

Comment: Please provide a complete program. It needs to be minimal, but still runnable.

Comment: Your `if wrongIdText is None:` check is pointless - *of course* it's None, you assigned that value two lines earlier!  If you want the value to persist between calls to the function, it cannot be a local variable - make it global, or an attribute of some global object.

Comment: For some reason, your solution Jason works in an MRE but in my project it doesn't. I've edited the post to include the MRE.

Comment: Nvm Jason, it works now, I'll flag your answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was posted by jasonharper as a comment:

> Your if wrongIdText is None: check is pointless - of course it's None, you assigned that value two lines earlier! If you want the value to persist between calls to the function, it cannot be a local variable - make it global, or an attribute of some global object.

Thanks to Him and to Bryan for the help!

I fixed the problem by declaring my label's variable as global in the top of my code and assigning a None value to it using `global wrongIdText` and I've modified the code accordingly:

```
def updateWrongIdText(id):
    global wrongIdText
    if doesIdExist(id):
        if wrongIdText is not None:
            wrongIdText.destroy()
    else:
        if len(id) == 0:
            if wrongIdText is not None:
                wrongIdText.destroy()
            wrongIdText = customtk.CTkLabel(master=loginFrame, text="Sorry, Studnet Id case cannot be empty", font=('Chalkboard', 12), text_color="red")
            wrongIdText.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.8, anchor = "center")
        else:
            if wrongIdText is not None:
                wrongIdText.destroy()          
            wrongIdText = customtk.CTkLabel(master=loginFrame, text="Sorry, this Student ID is not registerd in our Library", font=('Chalkboard', 12), text_color="red")
            wrongIdText.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.8, anchor = "center")
```

Comment: It is better to post the code that fix your issue.